# How kafka producer at client side work?

Tags: apache-kafka

assume that i own a kafka cluster and i ask for some clients(web apps) to send data to the Kafka , how i can make sure that the client who will create the producer to connect to my Kafka brokers will do the partition in the right way if the client will use custom partition-er ?

Comment: is this wrong way ? should i connect to these apps through my own producers ? or they should create their own producers ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible to restrict Kafka clients/cluster to use some partitioner. But if your producer is hidden behind some facade interface, you can probably check if the `Key` of your message has been created the right way.

Your facade can accept `ProducerRecord`s for example. In this case you have access to the `key` and `value` fields.

https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html